# What is the convergence rate of this "infinite monkey"-type probability?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

[Cross-posted from Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4888488/convergence-rate-of-infinite-monkey-type-probability?noredirect=1#comment10429091_4888488), where it hasn’t received an answer yet:

Let $S$ be a finite set and $n,m\in\mathbb N$. Consider the process $R=(R_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ where all $R_i$ are iid uniformly distributed on $S$. I am trying to tackle the probability of the event
\begin{equation}
A_m(n):=\{\exists_{1\leq i<j\leq m+n}: (R_i,\dots,R_{i+n-1}) = (R_j,\dots,R_{j+n-1})\}
\end{equation}
as $m\to\infty$. It is straight forward to prove $\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbb P(A_m(n)) = 1$, since the event "$(R_i,\dots,R_{i+n-1})=r$ infinitely often" constitutes a lower bound for every $r\in S^n$ and has probability $1$ using Borel-Cantelli.

I am now trying to find the rate of convergence of $\mathbb P(A_m(n))$ depending on $n$ but I am struggling to do so. It is clear that when $m< n$ the probability $\mathbb P(A_m(n))$ is rather small, since there necessarily would have to be an overlap with the two windows of length $n$. Moreover by the pigeonhole principle one can prove $\mathbb P(A_m(n))=1$ for $m$ large enough. However, I am interested in the convergence rate in between.

This question is related to the Infinite Monkey Theorem for which formulas for the expected hitting time of a certain word exist. But here I do not need to hit a specific word and I don't look at the expectation. Rather I am interested in hitting any word of length $n$ twice when hitting $n+m$ keys on the keyboard.

**Context** The question arises when looking at functions I deemed "autoregressive". See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4886283/combinatorics-for-autoregressive-functions-reference). I am happy to provide more context if needed.

I appreciate any sort of help/reference/hint !

Comment: Here's standard strategy.  Let $X_{m}(n) = X$ be the number of pairs $1 \leq i < j \leq m + n$ for which you have $(R_i,\ldots, R_{i+n-1}) = (R_j,\ldots,R_{j+n-1})$.  When $E X < 1$, you can use that as an upper bound on $A_{m}(n)$.  In fact the Bonferroni inequalities imply $ E X - E \binom{X}{2} \leq  P(A_m(n)) \leq E X$, so this will be good for when the mean is $\ll 1$.  When the mean grows, you can compute the variance and use Chebyshev.  If you really care, when the mean is constant, you can prove $X$ will be Poisson in the limit.